# LWC Datatable button navigation to record page does not work

Tags: lightning-web-components, debugging

I have a very simple datatable which has a column with a button that should navigate the user to the record page of the record row.

HTML template and JavaScript controller:

```
   import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { navigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import accounts from '@salesforce/apex/utils.getAccs';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'id', fieldName: 'Id'},
    { label: 'Action', type: 'button', typeAttributes: {
        iconName: 'action:preview',  
        label: 'View',  
        name: 'View',  
        title: 'View',  
        disabled: false,  
        value: 'view',  
        iconPosition: 'right'  
    }}
];

export default class DataTable extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(accounts) data;

    columns = columns;

    handleAction(event){
        if(event.detail.action.name=="View"){
            console.log(event.detail.action.name); //View
            console.log(event.detail.row.Name); //Name
            console.log(event.detail.row.Id); //Id

            this[navigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: event.detail.row.Id,
                    objectApiName: 'Account',
                    actionName: 'view'
                },
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Apex controller:

```
public with sharing class utils {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<Account> getAccs(){
        return [SELECT id, Name from Account];
    }
}
```

Data is displayed in the datatable, but after clicking the button, there is an error:

```
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
```

Comment: Summary: It's `NavigationMixin`. not `navigationMixin`, and you need to use it as a mixin: `export default class DataTable extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)`